# A error in htaccess for hosting plan review page

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/plan/([a-z0-9-]+)\-([0-9]+)/reviews/$    main.php?Type=HOSTING_PLAN_REVIEW_PAGE&MenuID=104&HostLink=$1&PlanLink=$2&PlanID=$3
```

Above .htaccess matches a page for Web Hosting Plan Review Page.
ex:

```
$1=godaddy $2=pro-plan $3=1001
```

The above .htaccess works fine in local WAMP server.

But it doesnt work on Website..

Whats the pblm?

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't work" is exactly?

Comment: the above htacess works for localhost
http://localhost/hostdime-india/plan/s1in-1/reviews/

But it doesnt workon below website
www.hostdekho.com/hostdime-india/plan/s1in-1/reviews/

Comment: But what "doesn't work"? You getting an error? You getting nothing? What does the logs say? "doesn't work" can mean a million things.